# UIScrollView return first image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a `UIScrollView` which I display 5 images within it. After the 5th image I want to go back to the first image. I have checked the apple docs methods and I believe using

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

might be a solution.Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `contentOffset` property:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Comment: using the - (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView method ? @ayankhan

Comment: its a delegate,it would be useful once you need to do some stuff after scroll,otherwise u can go with my solution.